# MacBook Air screen switches off randomly

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

Title says almost all of it, and no, it's not that my display sleeps after inactivity. It was 5 seconds after touching the keyboard, last time. It's done it twice so far.

Other thing is that when you hit some keys on the keyboard for a few seconds, and it turns back on, you hear a slight `bzzt` sound. Very slight.

Should I be worried?

Comment: Have you taken it into the Apple Store to get it checked out?